# Wcf: exception during deserialization operation

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

I've Wcf method that returns a dataset that contains about 100000 records. The size of body message is about 30 Mb uncompressed.
Sometime it works fine, but many times I receive following xml exception during deserialization operation:

> Error during deserialization of object System.Data.DataSet. Unexpected
>   end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed:
>   NumEffetto, Scadenze, NewDataSet, diffgram, GetChangesResult,
>   GetChangesResponse, Body, Envelope.'

Stack trace:

> in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc&
>   rpc) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) in
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) in
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) in Kronos.WCFSync.ISyncService.GetChanges(Int64
>   clientCTVersion, Int64 verPubblicazione, SyncParam[] parameters) in
>   Kronos.WCFSync.SyncServiceClient.GetChanges(Int64 clientCTVersion,
>   Int64 verPub, SyncParam[] parameters) in Kronos.SyncManager.Sync()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The problem was sendTimeout default value, it is too lower in my case (1 minute). I added in the web.config following elements within Binding tag and now it works fine:

```
<binding name="customBinding"
    closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
</binding>
```

Answer (score -2):

check whether reader quota is there in your web.config also change ResponseFormat in json

Comment: How do you know this is a webHttpBinding service? If not then json is not an option. Also, a readerQuotas violation is very visible as such in any error. This is clearly not caused by this/.